# Possible improvement of table code

Tags: tables

**Code**

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass[
  12pt,
  danish,
  landscape
]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[
  a3paper,
  hmargin = 0cm,
  vmargin = 4cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{
  ragged2e,
  array
}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xfp}


\def\mlr{2.5}
\newcommand*\mc[1]{
  \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\raisebox{\fpeval{-1/3*\mlr}ex}{\textbf{#1}}}
}
\newcommand*\saenk[1]{
  \raisebox{\fpeval{-5/9*\mlr}ex}{#1}%
}
\newcommand*\tid[2]{\saenk{#1\,--\,#2}}
\definecolor{morgen}{rgb}{0.7, 0.75, 0.7}
\definecolor{dansk}{rgb}{0.0, 0.0, 1.0}
\definecolor{matematik}{rgb}{0.89, 0.0, 0.13}
\definecolor{historie}{rgb}{1.0, 0.55, 0.0}
\definecolor{engelsk}{rgb}{0.6, 0.4, 0.8}
\definecolor{tysk}{rgb}{0.0, 0.5, 0.0}
\definecolor{krist}{rgb}{0.33, 0.33, 0.33}
\definecolor{samfund}{rgb}{0.5, 0.0, 0.5}
\definecolor{biologi}{rgb}{0.55, 0.71, 0.0}
\definecolor{geografi}{rgb}{0.68, 0.85, 0.9}
\definecolor{fysik}{rgb}{0.99, 0.99, 0.59}
\definecolor{idraet}{rgb}{0.96, 0.76, 0.76}
\definecolor{valgfag}{rgb}{1.0, 1.0, 0.0}
\definecolor{understoet}{rgb}{1.0, 1.0, 1.0}
\newcommand*\laerer[2]{%
  \cellcolor{#2}%
  \ifstrequal{#2}{krist}%
    {\textcolor{white}{\saenk{\MakeUppercase{\textbf{#1}}}}}%
    {\ifstrequal{#2}{dansk}%
      {\textcolor{white}{\saenk{\MakeUppercase{\textbf{#1}}}}}%
      {\ifstrequal{#2}{matematik}%
        {\textcolor{white}{\saenk{\MakeUppercase{\textbf{#1}}}}}%
        {\ifstrequal{#2}{tysk}%
          {\textcolor{white}{\saenk{\MakeUppercase{\textbf{#1}}}}}%
          {\ifstrequal{#2}{samfund}%
            {\textcolor{white}{\saenk{\MakeUppercase{\textbf{#1}}}}}%
            {\textcolor{black}{\saenk{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}}}}}}}
\newcommand*\lokale[2]{%
  \cellcolor{#2}%
  \ifstrequal{#2}{krist}%
    {\textcolor{white}{\saenk{\textbf{#1}}}}%
    {\ifstrequal{#2}{dansk}%
      {\textcolor{white}{\saenk{\textbf{#1}}}}%
      {\ifstrequal{#2}{matematik}%
        {\textcolor{white}{\saenk{\textbf{#1}}}}%
        {\ifstrequal{#2}{tysk}%
          {\textcolor{white}{\saenk{\textbf{#1}}}}%
          {\ifstrequal{#2}{samfund}%
            {\textcolor{white}{\saenk{\textbf{#1}}}}%
            {\textcolor{black}{\saenk{#1}}}}}}}}
\newcommand*\fag[2]{\laerer{#1}{#2}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\thickhline{%
    \noalign {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \hrule height 2pt
    \futurelet \reserved@a \@xhline
}
\newcolumntype{"}{@{\hskip\tabcolsep\vrule width 1pt\hskip\tabcolsep}}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{empty}


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \bfseries
  \fontsize{40}{48}\selectfont
  Skema for skoleåret~2021/2022
\end{center}
\vspace*{8ex}

\LARGE
\begin{center}
 \begin{tabular}{
        |>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}m{6.51cm}
   *{5}{|>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}m{1.85cm}
         >{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}m{2.16cm}
         >{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}m{0.95cm}}|
 }
  \hline
  {\bfseries\backslashbox{Tidsrum}{Ugedag}}
   & \mc{Mandag}
   & \mc{Tirsdag}
   & \mc{Onsdag}
   & \mc{Torsdag}
   & \mc{Fredag}  \\
  \hline
     \verb||\hphantom{1}%
     \tid{8:10}{8:25}
   & \laerer{AM}{morgen}     & \fag{MB}{morgen}     & \lokale{29}{morgen}
   & \laerer{KSP}{morgen}    & \fag{MB}{morgen}     & \lokale{29}{morgen}
   & \laerer{MAS}{morgen}    & \fag{MB}{morgen}     & \lokale{29}{morgen}
   & \laerer{MAS}{morgen}    & \fag{MB}{morgen}     & \lokale{29}{morgen}
   & \laerer{AM}{morgen}     & \fag{MB}{morgen}     & \lokale{29}{morgen} \\[\mlr ex]
  \hline
     \verb||\hphantom{1}%
     \tid{8:25}{9:10}
   & \laerer{AM}{valgfag}    & \fag{VALG}{valgfag}  & \lokale{29}{valgfag}
   & \laerer{KSP}{samfund}   & \fag{SAM}{samfund}   & \lokale{29}{samfund}
   & \laerer{MAS}{matematik} & \fag{MAT}{matematik} & \lokale{29}{matematik}
   & \laerer{MAS}{fysik}     & \fag{F/K}{fysik}     & \lokale{fys}{fysik}
   & \laerer{AM}{dansk}      & \fag{DAN}{dansk}     & \lokale{29}{dansk} \\[\mlr ex]
  \hline
     \verb||\hphantom{1}%
     \tid{9:10}{9:55}
   & \laerer{AM}{valgfag}    & \fag{VALG}{valgfag}  & \lokale{29}{valgfag}
   & \laerer{KSP}{samfund}   & \fag{SAM}{samfund}   & \lokale{29}{samfund}
   & \laerer{MAS}{matematik} & \fag{MAT}{matematik} & \lokale{29}{matematik}
   & \laerer{MAS}{fysik}     & \fag{F/K}{fysik}     & \lokale{fys}{fysik}
   & \laerer{AM}{dansk}      & \fag{DAN}{dansk}     & \lokale{29}{dansk} \\[\mlr ex]
  \thickhline
     \tid{10:25}{11:10}
   & \laerer{AM}{dansk}      & \fag{DAN}{dansk}     & \lokale{29}{dansk}
   & \laerer{AM}{dansk}      & \fag{DAN}{dansk}     & \lokale{29}{dansk}
   & \laerer{AA}{tysk}       & \fag{TYS}{tysk}      & \lokale{29}{tysk}
   & \laerer{AM}{dansk}      & \fag{DAN}{dansk}     & \lokale{29}{dansk}
   & \laerer{MAS}{geografi}  & \fag{GEO}{geografi}  & \lokale{29}{geografi} \\[\mlr ex]
  \hline
     \tid{11:10}{11:55}
   & \laerer{AA}{tysk}       & \fag{TYS}{tysk}      & \lokale{29}{tysk}
   & \laerer{AM}{dansk}      & \fag{DAN}{dansk}     & \lokale{29}{dansk}
   & \laerer{DN}{engelsk}    & \fag{ENG}{engelsk}   & \lokale{29}{engelsk}
   & \laerer{AM}{dansk}      & \fag{DAN}{dansk}     & \lokale{29}{dansk}
   & \laerer{LL}{krist}      & \fag{KRI}{krist}     & \lokale{29}{krist} \\[\mlr ex]
  \thickhline
     \tid{12:40}{13:25}
   & \laerer{MAS}{matematik} & \fag{MAT}{matematik} & \lokale{29}{matematik}
   & \laerer{MAS}{biologi}   & \fag{BIO}{biologi}   & \lokale{bio}{biologi}
   & \laerer{KSP}{idraet}    & \fag{IDR}{idraet}    & \lokale{hal}{idraet}
   & \laerer{AA}{tysk}       & \fag{TYS}{tysk}      & \lokale{29}{tysk}
   & \laerer{KSP}{historie}  & \fag{HIS}{historie}  & \lokale{29}{historie} \\[\mlr ex]
  \hline
     \tid{13:25}{14:10}
   & \laerer{MAS}{matematik} & \fag{MAT}{matematik} & \lokale{29}{matematik}
   & \laerer{MAS}{biologi}   & \fag{BIO}{biologi}   & \lokale{bio}{biologi}
   & \laerer{KSP}{idraet}    & \fag{IDR}{idraet}    & \lokale{hal}{idraet}
   & \laerer{DN}{engelsk}    & \fag{ENG}{engelsk}   & \lokale{29}{engelsk}
   & \laerer{KSP}{historie}  & \fag{HIS}{historie}  & \lokale{29}{historie} \\[\mlr ex]
   \thickhline
     \tid{14:25}{15:10}
   & \laerer{DN}{engelsk}    & \fag{ENG}{engelsk}   & \lokale{29}{engelsk}
   &                         &                      & 
   & \laerer{KSP}{idraet}    & \fag{IDR}{idraet}    & \lokale{hal}{idraet}
   &                         &                      & 
   & \laerer{MAS}{matematik} & \fag{MAT}{matematik} & \lokale{29}{matematik} \\[\mlr ex]
  \hline
 \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

**Question**

I actually think the code is acceptable (and the output is as I want it to be). I'm just wondering if it can be made more "elegant", as [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) has done [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/604283/improvement-of-ugly-looking-table) with a similar table. I know that elegant is subjective but if anyone is up for it, please let me know how you would improve the code.

**Update**

I can see that people have closed this question because it is opinion-based. I know that the question is that but why has it been closed because of it? The whole point is that I would like to see different approaches to improvement of the code.

Comment: The colors used here are terrible. I suggest to use colors in `ninecolors` package for proper color contrast: https://ctan.org/pkg/ninecolors

Comment: @L.J.R. What colors would you suggest?

Comment: I suggest to use black foreground color and different background colors of level 7 in `ninecolors`: red7, blue7, azure7, teal7, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of the programming language, if I see a lot of nested ifs, I start thinking in terms of either an array or hashmap. Now LaTeX doesn't actually have these data structures, but the hashmap is actually pretty easy to emulate.

What we want is to be able to have a mapping between a string (your argument #2) and a command. This is accomplished via the primitive `\csname`…`\endcsname` or the private LaTeX `\@namedef`.¹

Now we could define the commands that we want doing something like²:

```
\@namedef{skema@krist}#1{\textcolor{white}{\sank{#1}}}
```

for each of the options, but we may as well wrap all of this up in a new command to define them instead.

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\newskema}{m m}{
  \@namedef{skema@#1}##1{#2} % ⓿
}
\newskema{krist}{\textcolor{white}{\sank{#1}}}
\newskema{dansk}{...}
...
```

(The `##1` on the line marked ⓿ is to tell LaTeX that we're defining a macro with a single argument using plain TeX's syntax. If we wrote it as `#1` instead of `##1` it would put the text of our first argument there instead.)

Then to access the desired style, we can write, e.g.,

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\laerer}{mm}{%
  \cellcolor{#2}%
  \@nameuse{skema@#2}{\MakeUppercase{\textbf{#1}}% ❶
}
```

This requires explicit definitions for all the possibilities, though. If we want to have a default, need to define a new command to use in place of `\@nameuse` that checks to see if we have a defined command for the provided value and if not, it will use a default value.

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\skemause}{m}{%
   \@ifdefined{skema@#1}{%
      \@nameuse{skema@#1}%
   }%
   {%
      \@nameuse{skema@DEFAULT}% or whatever you call your default
   }%
}
```

and then replace the line marked ❶ with

```
  \skemause{#2}{\MakeUppercase{\textbf{#1}}% ❶
```

---

1. It looks like expl3 doesn't provide something as convenient to work with as `\@namedef`, although I'd be happy to be corrected on this.
2. Since we're using private commands, assume that we're wrapped in `\makeatletter`…`\makeatother`.

Comment: `\cs_new(_protected):cpn` and `\use:c`

Comment: Thanks alot. I'll look at your answer later.